# webpack/babel transpile to system.register

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I can successfully transpile es6 modules -> System.Register format using babel cli.

I would like to be able to transpile to System.Register format using babel from Webpack.

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-systemjs"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
.....
.....
loaders: [ { 
        test   : /.js$/,
        exclude : /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
    }
]
.....
.....
```

After running 'webpack', a warning is returned **System.register is not supported by webpack.**

I know this is self explanatory, my question is (which i have been unable to find the answer to after searching / investigating) -

Is this something that is going to be supported by webpack? Or if it is supported, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Pretty out-of-date answer, but you could try "commonjs". It gets worked for me.